# How to find exact month and days between two dates - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to calculate the month and days between two dates. Then need to calculate the cost to be paid by the user between the start date and end date.

Cost = 10000.00;
Periodicity = 3 (Quaterly);

No of months and days = (Start Date - End Date);

Payment Need to be paid = ((No of months and days / Periodicity) * Cost);

I try to find the time difference between two dates but it is not working properly for me. Can anyone help me?

```
var date = "2017-06-01";
            console.log("date: "+date);
            var currentDate = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            $scope.userdob = "2017-08-31";
            var dobdate = $filter('date')($scope.userdob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            console.log("dob: "+dobdate);

            /* differentiate Date */            
            var date1 = $filter('date')($scope.userdob, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            var date2 = $filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");

            date1 = date1.split('-');
            date2 = date2.split('-');

            // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several  helpful methods
            date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
            date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

            if (date1 < date2)
            {
                var start_date = date1;
                var end_date = date2;
                var inverse = false;

                end_date = new Date(end_date); //If you don't do this, the original date passed will be changed. Dates are mutable objects.
                end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1);

                // Calculate the differences between the start and end dates
                var yearsDifference = end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear();

                var monthsDifference = end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth();

                var daysDifference = end_date.getDate() - start_date.getDate();

                var d1 = new Date(end_date.getFullYear(), end_date.getMonth(), 0);
                var noOfDays = d1.getDate();

                $scope.noOfMonths = (inverse ? -1 : 1) * (yearsDifference * 12 + monthsDifference + daysDifference/noOfDays); // Add fractional month
```

Comment: what do you mean by month? whole 30-day period?

Comment: Playing around with dates is a pain, my advice would be to check out something like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) - while this doesn't answer your question, this library has saved me a tonne of time :) It will break down the actual calendar months and leap years etc

Answer (score 1):

```
function findDateDifferenceInDays(sdate,edate) {
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var firstDate = new Date(sdate);
    var secondDate = new Date(edate);

    return Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Date manipulation is notoriously tricky to get right. There's leap years, leap seconds, and other various forms of time adjustments that happen. For a big, but nowhere near exhaustive list, checkout [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) and [More falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time). Your best bet when doing something nontrivial with dates and times is to use a good library, such as [moment](https://momentjs.com/). It won't get everything right, of course, but it will do a good enough job for most purposes.

It can handle parsing for you as well, so the previous code can become something like this:

```
const date1 = moment($filter('date')($scope.userdob, "yyyy-MM-dd"));
const date2 = moment($filter('date')(date, "yyyy-MM-dd"));

const diffInMonths = date1.diff(date1, 'months');
const diffInDays = date1.diff(date2, 'days');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem.

```
$scope.startDate = new Date(startDate);

                $scope.endDate = new Date(endDate);

                console.log($scope.startDate);
                console.log($scope.endDate);

                /* differentiate Date */            
                var date1 = $filter('date')($scope.startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                var date2 = $filter('date')($scope.endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");

                console.log("date1 : "+date1);
                console.log("date2 : "+date2);

                date1 = date1.split('-');
                date2 = date2.split('-');

                // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
                /*date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
                date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);*/

                console.log("date1 : "+date1);
                console.log("date2 : "+date2);
                if ($scope.startDate < $scope.endDate)
                {
                    var start_date = date1;
                    var end_date = date2;
                    var inverse = false;
                    console.log("end_date : "+end_date);

                    end_date = new Date(end_date); //If you don't do this, the original date passed will be changed. Dates are mutable objects.
                   console.log("end_date : "+end_date); end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1);

                    start_date = new Date(start_date);


                    // Calculate the differences between the start and end dates
                    var yearsDifference = end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear();

                    var monthsDifference = end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth();

                    var daysDifference = end_date.getDate() - start_date.getDate();

                    var d1 = new Date(end_date.getFullYear(), end_date.getMonth(), 0);
                    var noOfDays = d1.getDate();

                    if(noOfDays >= 30) {
                        noOfDays = 30;
                    }

                    var days = daysDifference/noOfDays;

                    console.log(days);

                    $scope.noOfMonths = (inverse ? -1 : 1) * (yearsDifference * 12 + monthsDifference + days); // Add fractional month

                    console.log($scope.noOfMonths);
```